# AWS denied permission to view AMI details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

For some of our AMIs we're unable to see any information on them in the AWS console. Instead, what we're seeing is this message under AMI ID:

```
Cannot load details for ami-e470458e. You may not be permitted to view it.
```

How can I change permissions in IAM, so that I can view info for this and the other AMIs showing this message.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the AMI was removed by Amazon, for new AMI. In this case, likely due to old builds of your AMI type (Amazon's standard Windows or Linux builds of an old patch date.) As they update and release new images, the old ones are removed, resulting in this message.

You cannot change this for ami you did not create or control, including Amazon provided or community provided AMI.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your account is missing, or has a restricted `ec2:describeImages` permission. Without knowing exactly what IAM permissions are assigned to your AWS user account it's difficult to provide more detailed help.